# Is there a working NFC Bluetooth handover example for Android 8.0 and above?

Tags: android, bluetooth, nfc, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to write an Android app (for APIs 21-27) that initiates a Bluetooth connection between two devices when touched together using NFC, but I can't find a working example and the documentation on the subject is limited. I've already read the NFC Forum's document on [simple secure Bluetooth pairing](http://members.nfc-forum.org/apps/group_public/download.php/18688/NFCForum-AD-BTSSP_1_1.pdf) (both 1.0 and 1.1) but it is no help since it talks about sending a devices own MAC address, which can no longer be obtained

I've only been able to find two examples of NFC Bluetooth handover and both of them were from before Android nerfed the ability to get a device's own Bluetooth MAC address. Does anyone know of an NFC Bluetooth handover example that is current (>= Oreo) and works?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm not asking for a recommendation, which would be subjective. Nor am I asking anyone to find a resource for me as I have listed no such resource. I'm asking if anyone even knows of any more examples that _exist_ as I spent considerable time using Google and am hoping that someone with more knowledge than myself can provide direction